# Adding External Properties to an Object

Tags: java

Noob Java question here. I am wondering if there is a standard way to add additional/external properties to a POJO. i.e., say I have a `User` Object that I add to an `ArrayList` in my program. This Object will contain things like first name, last name, address, email, phone, etc., corresponding to whatever is defined in my database.

Now say that I have the requirement to include external attributes along with said `User`, such as Employer ID, Vehicle Plate #, Smartphone type. I will need to be able to include these extra properties when adding a `User` to my ArrayList - Is it possible to attach these strictly with Java so that I can have acces to them?

I've thought of going with something like a Value Object, in where the VO would include all the `User` Properties along with the extra fields to be added from outside Classes,  but want to explore more possibilities. Any ideas? Thanks much

Comment: you could extend class, and add new properties to type,

Answer (score 1):

You have many possibilities. Here are a few that immediately spring to mind:

1. Refactor the User class. This is the obvious one, so I presume you have a good reason for not doing so.
2. Write a class that extends User, containing this information. Presuming you're only storing this information for a subset of the users that this information applies to, this makes the most sense.
3. Use composition - create a new class that holds a user instance and then any other information you want to add to it.

Answer (score 1):

One big influence on what design you use will be whether all additional values are unique, or if a `User` can have multiple smartphones, vehicles, etc.

If all additional fields are all unique you can just slide in `java.util.Properties` (or other Maps). Your `User` class needs at least

```
import java.util.Properties;

class User
{
   Properties extra_attr = new Properties();

   // ... existing code ...

   public void setExtraAttr(String field, String value) {
       extra_attr.setProperty(field,value);
   }

   public String getExtraAttr(String field) {
       return extra_attr.getProperty(field);
   }
}
```

Then use calls like `some_user.setExtraAttr("Employer ID","314159");` and `some_user.getExtraAttr("Employer ID");` to set and get your extra attributes.

If you need multiplicity you may need a different approach, or you can just code over your implementation of `Properties`. For instance, you can rewrite `setExtraAttr()` to look for existing keys and add an index

```
  public void setExtraAttr(String field, String value) {
      if(extra_attr.getProperty(field) == null)
         extra_attr.setProperty(field,value);
      else {
         int index = 1;
         while(extra_attr.getProperty(field+index) != null)
            index++;
         extra_attr.setProperty(field+index,value);
      }
  }
```

You then need some kind of loop where ever you get attributes to look for and handle the multiple extra records.